# Architecture - 3D Modeling Library

Tags: object-oriented, architecture, encapsulation, extensibility

I'm writing a library to allow users to generate 3D models programatically.

- User writes code (e.g. `Square(4)`)
- User views preview of 3D model (with built in visualizer)
- User can "print" the model to a `.obj` file that can be read by other 3D modeling programs and visualizers

**What is a good way to architect the data objects and the above functionality?**

Lets assume a `Square` object subclasses a `Polygon` class.

A `Polygon` would have

- vertices
- a face
- a transformation/translation

Eventually, I need to be able to `print` this polygon to the screen.  Some part of my program will need to know how render it using a graphics library that I will use.  However I don't want to add this functionality as part of the `Polygon` class because I would like the `Polygon` class to only have to worry about pure geometric considerations, not details of graphics libraries.  So, I could just create a `Renderer` object that can take `Polygons` and `Circles` and `Curves` and inspect them and then decide how to display them, but that didn't seem very Object Oriented.

So to summarize, I want to have

- a bunch of different types of geometric objects (`Polygons`, `Circles`, `Curves`, etc)
- a few different ways to "print" the objects (display to screen, write to file, etc)

And I'm not sure where to put all of this functionality so that it is well encapsulated, easy to maintain, and extensible.

Comment: Have you looked at languages like Logo, postscript and HPGL?

Comment: I'm not looking for language recommendations, I already have a programming language and graphics framework that I will use.  I'm asking purely about software architecture patterns.

Comment: "well encapsulated, easy to maintain, and extensible" I can not tell you how to do that. But could you show some use-cases in object diagrams?

Comment: Look at how POV-Ray does it. Use that for inspiration. What makes the most sense is going to depend entirely on the application this software is going to solve, and you haven't indicated any purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comedically, and with good fortune, I found the above Wikipedia article that precisely describes my situation (what are the odds?).

> Consider the design of a 2D CAD system. At its core there are several types to represent basic geometric shapes like circles, lines and arcs...
>   one could apply the Visitor pattern. The Visitor pattern encodes a logical operation on the whole hierarchy into a single class containing one method per type.